# How can I convert JSON to Swift Dictinary inorder to make an HTTP POST

Tags: ios, json, swift

I am having issues to successfully structure my json data into a swift dictionary inorder to send my HTTP body via an API

This is how my Json is structured:

```
{
  "idNo": "string",
  "name": "string",
  "isRegistered": true,
  "customMessage": "string",
  "riskStatus": "Low",
  "exposureBasedRiskStatus": "Low",
  "symptomBasedRiskStatus": "Low",
  "riskMessage": "string",
  "doYouHaveATemperature": true,
  "temperature": 0,
  "asessmentQuestion": [
    {
      "question": "string",
      "answer": "string",
      "createdBy": "string"
    },
    {
      "question": "string",
      "answer": "string",
      "createdBy": "string"
    },
    {
      "question": "string",
      "answer": "string",
      "createdBy": "string"
    },
    {
      "question": "string",
      "answer": "string",
      "createdBy": "string"
    },
    {
      "question": "string",
      "answer": "string",
      "createdBy": "string"
    }
  ]
}
```

the object "asessmentQuestion" is an array of different questions, can't seem to figure out how to convert this structure to a swift dictionary or another recommended format for me to be able to post my data. My API is always saying bad request and I'm pretty sure I am not correctly mapping the json data.

this is a snippet of how I am attempting to map my json data:

```
   var dictionary = [String:Any]()
    
    dictionary["1. How old are you?"] = model.riskExposureBasedAssessment[0].answer
    dictionary["2. Have you ever visited a COVID affected country?"] = model.riskExposureBasedAssessment[1].answer
    dictionary["3. do you frequently experience flu like symptoms?"] = model.riskExposureBasedAssessment[2].answer
    dictionary["4. Where you providing care in a non-health setting for a person with symptomatic COVID-19 infection"] = model.riskExposureBasedAssessment[3].answer
    dictionary["5. Did you come in close contact* with a person with symptomatic laboratory-confirmed COVID-19 infection?"] = model.riskExposureBasedAssessment[4].answer
    
    let parameters = [
        "idNo": model.id,
        "name": model.name,
        "isRegistered": model.isRegistered,
        "customMessage": model.customResponse,
        "riskStatus": model.riskStatus,
             "exposureBasedRiskStatus": model.exposureBasedRiskStatus,
             "symptomBasedRiskStatus": model.symptomBasedRiskStatus,
             "riskMessage": model.riskMessage,
             "doYouHaveATemperature": model.doYouHaveATemperature,
             "temperature": model.temperature,
        "exposureBasedAssessments":  dictionary
        
        ] as [String:Any]
    
    
    
    let postData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters)
```

Comment: Did you try to reproduce this in Postman or Paw for example? Without the actual API documentation, there's no way we can tell what's wrong here.

Comment: Can you do at all `model.riskExposureBasedAssessment[0].question`? That would save you a lot. And you don't use Codable ?

Comment: Yes I did test it out in post man and it works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an array of dictionary, so :

```
var dictionaries: [[String: Any]] = []
// Populate dictionaries
// ...

let parameters = [
    "idNo": model.id,
    "name": model.name,
    "isRegistered": model.isRegistered,
    "customMessage": model.customResponse,
    "riskStatus": model.riskStatus,
    "exposureBasedRiskStatus": model.exposureBasedRiskStatus,
    "symptomBasedRiskStatus": model.symptomBasedRiskStatus,
    "riskMessage": model.riskMessage,
    "doYouHaveATemperature": model.doYouHaveATemperature,
    "temperature": model.temperature,
    "exposureBasedAssessments":  dictionaries    
    ] as [String:Any]
```

Then, to populate it:

```
var dict1: [String: Any] = [:]
dict1["question"] = "1. How old are you?"
dict1["answer"] = model.riskExposureBasedAssessment[0].answer
dictionaries.append(dict1)

var dict2: [String: Any] = [:]
dict2["question"] = "2. Have you ever visited a COVID affected country?"
dict2["answer"] = model.riskExposureBasedAssessment[1].answer
dictionaries.append(dict2)

...
```

or

```
var dict1: [String: Any] = ["question": "1. How old are you?",
                            "answer": model.riskExposureBasedAssessment[0].answer]
dictionaries.append(dict1)

var dict2: [String: Any] = ["question": "2. Have you ever visited a COVID affected country?"",
                            "answer": model.riskExposureBasedAssessment[1].answer]
dictionaries.append(dict2)

...
```

But, I guess you have can retrieve the question from `model.riskExposureBasedAssessment[n]`,
Instead of `"1. How old are you?"`, can't you do `model.riskExposureBasedAssessment[0].question`?

If that's the case, you can use a for loop:
so I'd go with:

```
for aQuestionModel in model.riskExposureBasedAssessment {
    let questionDict = ["question": aQuestionModel.question,
                        "answer": aQuestionModel.answer]
    dictionaries.append(questionDict)
}
```

Or, once you master basic algorithm, closures, and `map()`:

```
var dictionaries = model.riskExposureBasedAssessment.map { ["question": $0.question, "answer": $0.answer] }
```

It's missing the "createdBy", I don't know where to find it and if it's optional, but I think you should be able to add it if needed.

NotaBene:
Code not tested against a compiler. It should work, at maybe one or two typos.

Comment: Thanks for the simple and straight forward approach, I was complicating my lfe and hence confused myself.